# Google Forms sending me duplicate email on automatical email

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

So, I've used this code, just reworked for my needs:
[Can Google Forms send emails automatically?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/97848/can-google-forms-send-emails-automatically)

The problem I have is that the account that sends those emails also receives them. Is there a way to disable it? It's supposed to be used as a confirmation for event participation for 150+ people, so I don't want to flood my mailbox with thousands of those messages.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, stupid me, just had to remove `bcc` in `cosmetics`.
I though something else is the issue, becouse when I removed it I stopped receiving emails at all, turns out it was just some anti-flooding protection, and I used one email adress for testing.